# CMake cannot find z3++.h when building

Tags: c++, cmake, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm using "CMake Tools" extension in vscode on MacOS Big Sur, trying to use it to build a tool allowing me to debug my code. But I get stuck when using CMake to build it. I've tried several ways to tell CMake where Z3 is but end up nothing. Any advice would be very helpful, cause I'm totally a newbie to this. Thanks!

Below is the error messages

```
[main] Building folder: SVF 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.3/bin/cmake --build /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/Debug-build --config Debug --target all -j 6 --
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target Cudd
[build] [ 28%] Built target Cudd
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target Svf
[build] [ 29%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/DDAClient.cpp.o
[build] [ 29%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/ContextDDA.cpp.o
[build] [ 30%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/DDAStat.cpp.o
[build] [ 31%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/DDAPass.cpp.o
[build] [ 31%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/FlowDDA.cpp.o
[build] [ 32%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/Graphs/ExternalPAG.cpp.o
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/lib/DDA/FlowDDA.cpp:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/DDA/FlowDDA.h:12:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/DPItem.h:33:
[build] /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/Conditions.h:37:10: fatal error: 'z3++.h' file not found
[build] #include "z3++.h"
[build]          ^~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/lib/DDA/DDAStat.cpp:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/DDA/FlowDDA.h:12:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/DPItem.h:33:
[build] /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/Conditions.h:37:10: fatal error: 'z3++.h' file not found
[build] #include "z3++.h"
[build]          ^~~~~~~~
[build] 1 error generated.
[build] 1 error generated.
[build] make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/FlowDDA.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[build] make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/DDAStat.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/lib/DDA/DDAClient.cpp:16:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/DDA/FlowDDA.h:12:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/DPItem.h:33:
[build] /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/Conditions.h:37:10: fatal error: 'z3++.h' file not found
[build] #include "z3++.h"
[build]          ^~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/lib/DDA/DDAPass.cpp:11:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/DDA/FlowDDA.h:12:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/DPItem.h:33:
[build] /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/Conditions.h:37:10: fatal error: 'z3++.h' file not found
[build] #include "z3++.h"
[build]          ^~~~~~~~
[build] 1 error generated.
[build] 1 error generated.
[build] make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/DDAClient.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/DDAPass.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/lib/DDA/ContextDDA.cpp:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/DDA/ContextDDA.h:13:
[build] In file included from /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/DPItem.h:33:
[build] /Users/myname/Programs/SVF/include/Util/Conditions.h:37:10: fatal error: 'z3++.h' file not found
[build] #include "z3++.h"
[build]          ^~~~~~~~
[build] 1 error generated.
[build] make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/DDA/ContextDDA.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/Svf.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make: *** [all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles: As far as I understand, the asker builds that project: https://github.com/SVF-tools/SVF.

Comment: "I've tried several ways to tell CMake where Z3 is ..." - So, where Z3 is installed on your PC, and where exactly `z3++.h` header is located?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think they already have Z3 installed but want cmake to link to it. Either way they need to show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles: For hint CMake about a package (Z3 in the given case) one need to firstly know location of that package, or at least the way the package was installed. As for given project, it can be hinted with `Z3_DIR` environment variable: https://github.com/SVF-tools/SVF/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L54. Alternatively, it searches for Z3 using `pkg-config`, but in that case resulted **include directory** is **ignored** (there is no usage of `Z3_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable in the code). Probably, this is a reason of the error message.